How to include custom css file in Remix Shopify app template?
I am struggling with including custom style in shopify remix app.
import styles from './styles/custom.css';
export function links() {
  return [{ rel: 'stylesheet', href: styles }];
}

But I am getting this error

Failed to load url ./styles/custom.css (resolved id:
./styles/custom.css) in C:/PATH/app/routes/app.funnels.jsx. Does the
file exist?

